# how to make navbar initially hidden in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the navbar of my website initially hidden and when scrolling down it should show up.
just like snowehome.com

my code for navbar is very small and as shown below:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                 <center><a href="#"><img id="img_nav" src="images/Logo Full.png"></a></center>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: so add the `hidden` class

Answer (score 0):

Just add the hidden class or if you wish to hide it without bootstrap and simply CSS

```css
.navbar {
  display: none;
  }

/*If you want to have navbar invisible but its position, margins, and paddings intact*/

.navbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: I just wanna hide the navbar in when I first enter the website. Its invertedsense.netai.net   and other effects on scrolling is done. Just wanna hide the navbar when someone reloads/visits the website.

Comment: Ok I think I know what the question is let me edit my answer real quick